# Megamenu disappears when hover cuz of margin top

Tags: html, css

Hi Stack overflow people!

I have a small problem I need some help to fix. I tried google youtube etc...

I have a navigation bar with a button. I my navigation a have a megamenu dropdown this is where the problem is. When is hover over the navigation where the megamenu it goes through my button which looks awful. I tried to margin-top so it goes down a bit, but then when I try to go in the megamenu it now disappears because there is space between the menu and the megamenu. Is there a way to move down the megamenu a bit without it disappears ?

I tried margin-top and haven't found any solution to the problem yet

Comment: Hi, please post your minimally reproducible code. So we can look and see what is actually happening

Comment: Hi! I linked the github because i dont know where the problem is! HTML: https://github.com/Magnusgb/redbarnetungdom/blob/main/Magnus/dropdown/dropdown.html. CSS: https://github.com/Magnusgb/redbarnetungdom/blob/main/Magnus/dropdown/style1.css

Comment: I've forked the repo and I am not seeing the behavior you are describing.